# How to disable zoom for my secondary monitor

Tags: display, zoom

My secondary monitor on my computer is zoomed in so I cannot see the taskbar or the top of my screen. I know this is done for TVs for widescreen, but how do I disable that? I have a ViewSonic VX2453 Series monitor. When I fullscreen a tab, it cuts off all sides of it about an inch or two.

Comment: You need to change the Over-/Underscan setting in your graphics driver. What GPU do you have? AMD, NVIDIA or Intel? Or something entirely different?

Comment: @DanielB I have a Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme Core Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the options menu on the ViewSonic VX2453 Series monitor with 1, select Input Select, and change the input currently used to the PC option, not the AV option.